# How can i stop running exe in C# to start a new instance?

Tags: c#, running-other-programs

I have a server software that is written in C#. Sometimes I take this error:

> Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\Server.exe" to "bin\Debug\Server.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Server.exe' because it is being used by another process.

How can I understand that my program is still running in background and stop that?

Comment: I want to realize that with my software, not windows task manager.

Comment: If I understand this right you get this error while compiling. You code is not even running now to see, if another instance of it is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most probably caused not by your software (the one you are writing), but by IDE itself.

I usually just use Task Manager to kill whatever `vshost` process is still hanging, but that may not be very safe. Or sometimes all it takes is to restart Visual Studio.